# PHP/MYSQL - Return column name where variable matches datapoint

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query which in Psuedo MYSQL says:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = $x OR col2 = $x"
```

Now I am iterating through each line of the results but want to determine for each one which column x is in. Therefore I want to be able to return `column_name` where the variable `$x == $x` in the table.

I have tried using `fetch_field()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to add one more column to the resultset that indicates from which column the searched value comes from

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    case when col1 = :x then 'col1' else 'col2' end which_col
FROM table t
WHERE :x IN (col1, col2)
```

Side notes:

- you do want to use parameterized queries for efficiency and safety - more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- you should take the habit to enumerate the columns that you want in the `select` clause rather than using blindly `select *` - this makes the query easier to understand and maintain, and can make your code more efficient
- you can use then `IN` to shorten the condition in the `WHERE` clause a little